# Camel invoke direct: route (from()) within your application

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

My code is using Spring Boot and Camel v3. The route is currently define as:

```
 from("direct:handler").routeId("uniqueHandlerId").process([some bean]);
```

I need to find a way to call this route dynamically from my code.
I've tried to use ProducerTemplate and Camelcontext without any luck.
One of the issue i'm running into while using above class is route list is empty.

How do i call this route from my code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i found. 
If you explicitly load the route to the context. 
You'll be able to call it using producerTemplate. Here is sample that worked for me.

```
    @Autowired
    protected CamelContext camelContext;

    @Autowired
    CustomRouteBuilder customRouteBuilder;

    @Autowired
    ProducerTemplate template;

    public void post() {
      try {
         camelContext.addRoutes(customRouteBuilder);
         template.getCamelContext().start();
         template.send("direct:handler", [processor]);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```